# Nestjs Firebase Functions error when not warmed up

Tags: google-cloud-functions, nestjs

I'm getting weird issue with NestJS API running on google firebase functions.
When I try to hit the API after a longer time (instance is not loaded), I get an error response. But the strange things is that this error is returned before the NestJS API is even initialized. Any idea what to look for?

Here is a screenshot of logs where You can see that function execution finished before "Nest Ready" is outputed.

[image]

When I hit the API after the instance is initialized, there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was how I handled the initiation of express server. It was returning response before the whole nestjs app was initialized. After I moved the logic to onRequest method, it works correctly.

```
export const api: functions.HttpsFunction = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
      if (!server) {
        bootstrap().then(() => server(req, res));
      } else {
        server(req, res);
      }
    });
```